# Main Thread is stuck when using NSBlockOperation and EKEventStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having a problem while using `NSBlockOperation` and trying to access `EKEventStore`. This is my code:

- this code is runing in Async

  ```
          NSBlockOperation *wordsOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
              //call a syncronous call to get the words dictionary
              NSLog(@"Before Get Word with ID: %@",resourceID);
              NSDictionary *wordsDic = [self getWordsForResourceID:resourceID];
              NSLog(@"After Get Word with ID: %@",resourceID);

          }];
  ```
- This code is runing on the Main Thread

  ```
      return [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
  ```
- This is my Debug Navigator:

[image]

BTW: the main thread will Release after the NSBlockOperation is Done

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. So basically i created to much NSBlockOperation in the NSOperationQueue this create to many threads. Apparently when the EKEventStore try to authorizationStatusForEntityType he tries to do so in the new Thread and wait until he is done. ( we can see that in the semaphore wait trap ). So the Solution was to limit the number of operation in the NSOperationQueue. this fix the Problem.